# How to enable web setup wizard in Magento 2.4?

Tags: web-setup-wizard

In the admin panel, the normal Web Setup Wizard page is not showing. But there is no error in the front end. What might be the cause of this ? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been removed in Magento 2.4.x

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/magento/magento-marketplace.html
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/tools.html

[image: Web Setup Wizard - Removed]